# Bug after rotate, using iCarousel as scroll view

Tags: ios, objective-c, icarousel

i use iCarousel lib as a scroll view for my app. The purpose of that library is to manage auto scrolling images. Image is set as a bounds of iCarousel class (which is actually `UIView`. It work fine, when initially loaded, but when i rotate device, it output odd bug. For example if i swipe from portrait to landscape, for fraction of second we can see following:
[image]

Then:[image]

For some reason we see "old" pictures

Here is how i declare main method for displaying views:

```
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view {



    NewScrollerItemForIPad *item;



    NewsItemMdl *mdl = self.viewModel.arrNews[index];
    if(mdl){

        /* Check for orientation */
        BOOL _isPortrait;

        if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation)){
            _isPortrait = NO;
        } else {
            _isPortrait = YES;
        }

        if (self.gotNews){

        if(!item){
            item = [[NewScrollerItemForIPad alloc] initWithFrame:car.bounds andOrientation:_isPortrait]; 
        }
        [item bindViewModel:mdl];
        }
    }
    return item;

}
```

And auto scrolling method:

```
-(void)runMethod{

    if(self.sliderCount== (self.pageControl.numberOfPages-1)){

        NSLog(@"Here we call");
        self.pageControl.currentPage = 0;
        self.sliderCount = 0;

        [car scrollToItemAtIndex:self.sliderCount animated:YES];

    }else{
        NSLog(@"And here we call");
        self.sliderCount++;
        self.pageControl.currentPage ++;
        [car scrollToItemAtIndex:self.sliderCount animated:YES];
    }

}
```

How to fix that bug? Obviously i dont want to future and old image to be loaded between new.

Comment: I'm not sure it is a _feature_ or a _bug_ in `iCarousel`, but I can tell you its implementation and behaviour are very-very odd (mostly buggy) – what we did to resolve the problems after orientation has changed we invoke the `–reloadData` method on the actual `iCarousel` instance every occasion.

Comment: @holex i did call     [car reloadData]; in - (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {, but unfortunnately problem isnt dissapear.

Comment: it would not really help on you if you reload the data _before_ the actual rotation happens; you need to do it _after_.

Comment: @holex okay, i'll try, thank you!:)

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban I also have the same problem with iCarousel. When I run reloadData after screen was rotated I can see old size of carousel for a second. It looks not so pretty. Could you tell me please how did you solve this problem? Maybe you should add your your answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

*Language*: **Swift**

Reload the Carousel view as follows:

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
    coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { _ in
        self.yourCarouselView.reloadData()
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

Use the following delegate method to decide the item width:

```
func carouselItemWidth(_ carousel: iCarousel) -> CGFloat {
    return yourCarouselView.bounds.width //Whatever the size you want to set
}
```

And

```
yourCarouselView.isPagingEnabled = true
```

Comment: Perfect.  Frame instead of Bounds `yourCarouselView.frame.width` for `carouselItemWidth:` was culprit in my case.